# Difference between websql and sqllite in aspect of mobile and web browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, sqlite, web-sql

please let me know, if both are same or not.

is websql and sqllite, both are available in Phone gap?

the Javascript Code which is used for web sql in web browser will be same for the mobile app or any other code do we need??

what is the advantage of web sql over sqlLite?

how about memory which is used in mobile for the case of websql?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121761/phonegap-websql-or-sqlite) that ask for the same.

[This other one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated) indicates that webSQL is deprecated. I would go with SQLlite, it is fairly simple to work with, and being SQL there should not be an issue switching to other SQL DBMS after all ;-). The post suggest to go with [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/IndexedDB) instead.